# How to save canvas background image to Json separately from other objects

Tags: javascript, json, canvas, fabricjs

I want to save objects on canvas and image under other objects to DB. And i can do that for all objects on canvas:

```
var jsonToPHP= JSON.stringify(canvas.toObject(['id','name','selectable']));
```

But when I want to use 2 json variables; one just for background image:
 and other for other objects on canvas.... then I am in big trouble.

I have two columns in DB. I want to send just background image to one and all other objects to other column. So i might edit just background when i wish.

I am trying different solutions almost for 10 days now. And .... i can not find the way.  I have a lot of code, and.... probably is better, if i start from nothing.

////////////// update1

```
function getbackgroundImageF(){ ////////////////////////////////////                              JSgetBackground
var fromSelectProject=document.getElementById("selectProject").value; 
$.ajax({
  method:"POST",
  url: '/wp-content/themes/myP/PgetJson.php',
  data:  {
    "getbackgroundImage":1,
    "whichProject":fromSelectProject
    },
    datatype: "text",
    success: function(strdate){
  canvas.loadFromJSON(strdate, function() {
    canvas.renderAll();
     });
     }
 });
}
document.getElementById("getbackgroundImageID").onclick = getbackgroundImageF;
```

Error from server ( r.ajaxTransport(function(b) {)

> if (h.open(b.type, b.url, b.async, b.username, b.password),

Comment: Maybe next idea could work:  To have two canvases. One transparent with objects on it and another canvas under it with image on it. I it possible to set one canvas to be  transparent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NO!!** You don't really need two canvases. One canvas would be enough to achieve this.

The idea is quite simple.

**Saving only background image to JSON :**

- remove* all the objects from canvas, except background image
- save canvas as JSON string
- add all the objects back to the canvas

**Saving only objects to JSON :**

- remove the background image from canvas
- save canvas as JSON string
- add the background image back to the canvas

<sub>* store before removing, so we can add them later</sub>

Here I have created a dummy example that portrays the idea in action :

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var JSONString_BGImage, JSONString_Objects;

//add rectangles
var rect1 = new fabric.Rect({
   top: 100,
   left: 30,
   width: 100,
   height: 100,
   fill: '#07C'
});
var rect2 = new fabric.Rect({
   top: 100,
   left: 170,
   width: 100,
   height: 100,
   fill: '#FF0'
});
canvas.add(rect1, rect2);

//set background image
canvas.setBackgroundImage('https://i.imgur.com/Q6aZlme.jpg', canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));

function toJSON(only) {
   if (only === 'bgImage') onlyBgImage();
   else if (only === 'objects') onlyObjects();
}

function fromJSON(only) {
   if (only === 'bgImage' && JSONString_BGImage) {
      canvas.clear(); //clear canvas
      canvas.loadFromJSON(JSONString_BGImage);
   } else if (only === 'objects' && JSONString_Objects) {
      canvas.clear(); //clear canvas
      canvas.loadFromJSON(JSONString_Objects);
   }
}

function onlyBgImage() {
   var objects = canvas.getObjects(); //get all objects, that are on canvas
   var clonedObjects = [];
   while (objects.length !== 0) {
      clonedObjects.push(objects[0].clone()); //clone objects, so we can add them later
      canvas.remove(objects[0]); //remove objects
   }
   JSONString_BGImage = JSON.stringify(canvas.toJSON()); //only contains background image
   canvas.add.apply(canvas, clonedObjects); //add cloned objects
}

function onlyObjects() {
   canvas.backgroundImage = null; //remove background image
   JSONString_Objects = JSON.stringify(canvas.toJSON()); //only contains objects
   canvas.setBackgroundImage('https://i.imgur.com/Q6aZlme.jpg', canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas)); //re-add background image
}
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid black }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.16/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="300" height="300"></canvas><br>
<b>Background Image : </b>
<button onclick="toJSON('bgImage')">toJSON</button>
<button onclick="fromJSON('bgImage')">fromJSON</button><br><br>
<b>Canvas Objects : </b>
<button onclick="toJSON('objects')">toJSON</button>
<button onclick="fromJSON('objects')">fromJSON</button>
```

<sup>the code above, is pretty much self explanatory. even after that, if you have any trouble understanding, please let me know.</sup>

Comment: Hi gaand. I believe your code is fine solution. But i would like to make it work in my application. Now i have still problems. I have edited my initial question with "upadate1" label. I have some problems with server. (check quotes). I can see my data in DB (with phpMyAdmin). But i can not retrieve it back. Do you may  have an idea what should be the problem or can You instruct me how to proceed with debugging, pleas?

Comment: I need to go back to earlier development phase of my project and to rebuilt some things. Then i will be back to this in next days. Thank you.

Comment: Good Luck !!­­­